Clustering multiple longitudinal variables
I wish to do longitudinal cluster analysis of 51 individuals, each with 11 variables, each measured 23 times at even intervals. What I have been able to find of longitudinal clustering seems to presume that you have only one variable, and that you already know the number of trajectories in the system. I have 11 variables and don't know beforehand how many trajectories I have.

I think what you are looking for is called multivariate growth mixture modeling; there aren't many examples in the literature, but it seems it has been used in this and this article. However, I'm fairly sure 51 participants is way too little to fit such a model, it's probably barely enough to fit a univariate growth mixture model.

Bengt Muthén also provides some advice in this old thread
